# sprintf php - How does it work?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, printf

I am using a theme using sprintf which I am very new to. I cannot get custom support from the developer on this so I am trying to figure it out on my own.

Not understanding how sprintf works, I've Googled loads of pages trying to find a fix to what I thought would have been simple.

The theme uses %s to load a text string, in this case the title of the page. I just want the title to link to the page! That's it! No less, no more. I was able to come up with something close below:

```
// Featured columns
case 'columns':
    $count = Website::getThemeOption('front_page/columns/count');
    $classes = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
    $columns = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        extract(Website::getThemeOption('front_page/columns/column/'.$i, true)->toArray());
        $text = DroneFunc::stringToHTML($text, false);
        if ($more && $link) {
            $text .= sprintf(' <a href="%s" class="more">%s</a>', $link, $more);
        }
        $columns[] = sprintf(
            '<li class="column">'.
                '<img src="%s/data/img/icons/32/%s" alt="" class="icon">'.
                '<h1><a href="%1$s">%s</a></h1><p>%s</p>'.
            '</li>',
            Website::get('template_uri'), $icon, $title, $text
        );
    }
    ?>
    <section class="columns <?php echo $classes[$count-1]; ?> clear">
        <ul>
            <?php echo implode('', $columns); ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <?php
    break;
```

Now originally, there was no hyperlink reference... I added that in. What this does now is make the h1 title clickable but it just goes to the root of the theme folder, not the title's page.

Any help in understanding this and making it work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ...and you did read the php manual on [sprintf](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)?

Comment: @Roblll: I did. I get the concept of how it works but don't know enough to get it to do what I need.

Comment: Well, if you get the concept, can you explain to me why you wrote `%1$s` in the href attribute? Shouldn't that be `%s`? So again: are you sure you get the concept? And aren't you missing a parameter specifying the actual url to go into the href? Why not experiment a little with the function in a separate .php file?

Comment: Please state what you expected and what you actually got

Comment: Damn you guys are being harsh. This site is to gather feedback for learning purposes, right. Obviously I don't exactly know what I'm doing so give me a little slack. I will edit my post again with additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Sprintf` basix

`Sprintf` adds the parameters to the first parameter at the place of the placeholders (which begins with `%`).

For instance:

```
$name = 'Rob';
$str = sprintf('Hello, I am %s', $name); // become: Hello, I am Rob
```

The letter after `%` is the first letter of the type of the parameter. A string is `%s`, an decimal is `%d`. For instance:

```
$name = 'Rob';
$age = 26;
$str = sprintf('Hello, I am %s and I am %d years old.', $name, $age);
// become: Hello, I am Rob and I am 26 years old.
```

`Sprintf` use the order of the parameters to determine where to place it in the string. The first placeholder gets the second parameter, the second placeholder the thirth, ect.
If you want to change this, you need to specify this between `%` and the type. You do this by `<place>$` where `<place>` is the place nummer.

```
$name = 'Rob';
$age = 26;
$str = sprintf('Hello, I am %2$s and I am %1$d years old.', $age, $name);
// become: Hello, I am Rob and I am 26 years old.
```

## The answer

You do this:

```
'<h1><a href="%1$s">%s</a></h1><p>%s</p>'
```

The `%1$s` is the first parameter, which is the `template_uri`. I think this isn't the url which you want to link to? You want to link to the uri in `$link`. Just place that in the parameters and refer to it:

```
sprintf(
    '...'.
    '<h1><a href="%s">%s</a></h1><p>%s</p>',
    Website::get('template_uri'), $icon, $link, $title, $text
);
```

Comment: No, and I understand I did it incorrectly. What I was trying to do was link to the page. Thanks for your input Wouter J.

Comment: That did it, many, many thanks! What I did initially was copy from another site what I thought may work and was experimenting. What you have shown me is I needed to add the parameter and simply refer to it where I wanted it to work. Awesome work Wouter. You have saved me such a headache. I have been back and forth with this for weeks and decided to really try and figure it out today :)